# Drawing a line between one CGPoint and another

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I have 2 CGPoints and a would like to draw straight line between them, how would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, point1.x, point1.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point2.x, point2.y);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

Comment: Joshua: Well, read what they say. The most likely reason why the context is invalid is that you haven't pasted this code into the correct place. Try putting the code into a method where there would be a valid current drawing context.

Comment: I've put it into the touchesEnd: method of an UIView.

Comment: -touchesEnded: is not a location where you have a valid current drawing context.  What Peter's referring to is somewhere like -drawRect: of a custom UIView subclass.  You then would trigger the redraw of a view using -setNeedsDisplay.  The UIView class reference has more: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:

Comment: I've put it into a new method, following your suggestion, as you can see here http://grab.by/1teD,  but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment.  Quartz drawing for display to the screen needs to be done in a specific place within a UIView subclass (within -drawRect:), and nowhere else. Read the following section of the iPhone Application Programming Guide for an example of this: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW15

Comment: Oh. But what about if you want to trigger more than one thing which draws, for example my touchesMoved: method draws a line but I also need to use drawRect: to draw a gradient background. How do I separate them?

Comment: And even when I put it into a drawRect: method I get the same error.

Comment: There are a couple of ways of approaching drawing multiple things: different UIViews for different drawing elements that are layered on top of one another (my recommendation, because you don't need to redraw all items any time a single one changes) or having the drawing code for all items within a single -drawRect: method.  The Quartz drawing calls are executed in order, with later items overlaying earlier ones.

Comment: In regards to the drawing errors, be sure that you are not calling drawRect: directly.  If you need to refresh the UIView, call -setNeedsDisplay on the view instead.

Comment: I see, How would I layer UIViews then?

Comment: Place one UIView on top of another, either by making the overlay view a subview of the underlying view or by putting both at the same location in a shared superview, with one ordered before the other.  I suggest reading the following section of the iPhone Application Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW47